# The state of a custom UITableViewCell after the Delete control has been dismissed

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've created a custom `UITableViewCell` that provides a single custom `UIView` for its contentView. The custom UIView uses CoreText so that I can display bibliographic data with book titles or journal titles in italics. The table displays correctly, and the text is adjusted if you swipe the row. However, if you dismiss the control, the adjusted text is just expanded to fill the space and appears bloated. I can see that `drawRect` is called in the content view when the cell is first displayed and when the control appears. However, it is not called when the control is dismissed.

How should I be handling the dismissal of the delete control? Should I be asking for the cell to be redrawn at some specific point in the lifecycle?

The table with custom cells:

[image: The table view with custom cells]

Table cell with the control:

[image: Custom table cell with a delete control]

Table cell after the delete control has been dismissed:

[image: Custom table cell after the delete control has been dismissed]

Comment: I'd love to read the book that has those three citations as its bibliography.

Comment: It turns out that Probabilistic w-automata isn't great for shaping a baby's brain ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `contentMode` property of your custom content view to `UIViewContentModeRedraw`. This will cause your view to, as it sounds, redraw itself when its bounds changes. If your layout is done in drawRect based on the bounds rectangle, this should sort it for you.